# Trying To Make A Randum Number Generator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers

i'm prettyt new to javascript and am making a random number generator, im using prompts to set low numbers and high numbers for the generator but it's not working. help? (code below)

```js
var highnumber = prompt("Enter Your High Number\nMax 10000");
var lownumber = prompt("Enter Your High Number\nMax 9998");

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (highnumber - lownumber)) + 1
}

alert(getRandomInt(100));
```

Comment: Can you describe how is it not working? What do you do to trigger the problem? What happens? What should happen instead?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

in order to get a random number between `lownumber` and `highnumber` you should do:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (highnumber - lownumber)) + lownumber
```

here you can see some examples between `135` and `142` (just to show it works)

```js
const randomNumber = (lownumber, highnumber) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (highnumber - lownumber)) + lownumber
}


for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(randomNumber(135, 142));
}
```